# Оповещение пользователя на сайте (как вконтакте)

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, websocket, long-poll

Пытаюсь понять как грамотно реализовать систему оповещений на сайте, подобно вк - у пользователя, которого касается событие, всплывает оповещение о новом сообщении в чате, комментарии под каким-либо постом и т.д.
Знаю, что у вк это сделано с помощью long polling. Также знаю, что это можно сделать и с помощью websocket и Server-sent events.  Я пытался найти примеры реализации подобного на PHP и впал в ступор. Основной аспект обработчиков событий (будь то long polling или же SSE) - это проверка изменения в БД в бесконечном while(true), но по моему мнению, если в бесконечно цикле постоянно долбить запросами БД, то рано или поздно при большем количестве пользователь база тупо не выдержит.
В этом и заключается вопрос, как грамотно реализовать эти оповещения и похожие механизмы с БД + long polling (websocket, SSE) без бесконечных опросов в базу? Возможно я что-то упускаю в этом моменте.
Я также слышал о способе с созданием отдельной таблицы для эвентов, которая точно также постоянно опрашивается, и если там появляются записи, то сервер отсылает сообщение и удаляет запись из БД, но опять же, это бесконечные запросы в БД.

Comment: Нужно не в цикле отправлять от себя запросы, появились ли изменения, а наоборот принимать к себе уведомления об изменениях. Делается это вообще без участия БД любым pubsub-сервером (Redis, RabbitMQ и подобные), но как это всё дружить с php, я не в курсе

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть как это устроено в той же Laravel, там это осуществляется с помощью уведомлений (notifications) и эхо сервиса (echo service)